# Einstein for Service

Tags: servicecloud, einstein

My Customer Service Team is requesting that we add a number of AI-like features to our Service solution.  Many of there requests seem to fit the profile of Einstein for Service.  In March, a number of blogs posted about new features coming to Einstein for Service - of particular interest is Einstein Reply and Einstein Article Recommendation.

I have tried to find information within Salesforce's documentation and continually come up blank.  I have reached out to my Salesforce Reps and they haven't come back to me with answers.

Primary Requests:

1) Present Salesforce Knowledge Articles to agent based on email body and update as the agent populates the details field. [Einstein Article Recommendations]

2) Provided automatic responses to common inquiries. [Einstein Reply]

3) Automatic identification and closure of junk messages. [Einstein Case Classification]

4) Auto-populate Case Fields from Email Content (beyond Email, Case, Case Contents) [Einstein Case Routing/Einstein Case Classification]

Does anyone have experience with Einstein for Service?  Is this a dead product?

Blogs mentioning features:

https://www.salesforceben.com/einstein-for-service-4-new-salesforce-einstein-features-for-service-cloud/

https://www.sailfin.tech/understanding-salesforce-service-cloud-einstein/

Comment: _My Customer Service Team is requesting that we add a number of AI-like features to our Service solution_ - what are their top 3 requests, if you don't mind sharing

Comment: I updated by question with the four primary requests.